# What incense to use for melee build?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I am running a melee build (Str/Dex), and have dipped a bit into Attunement (3 spell slots) for extra versatility.

For now I am using Pyromancy only. However, I have collected quite a bit on Spices (Sceptic/Simpleton), and I am wondering what to use them on.

I will probably use them on a single sorcery/miracle/hex, but which one to choose for maximum utility?

My current build is:

- SL 106
- VGR 25
- END 20
- VIT 26
- ATN 16
- STR 25
- DEX 22
- ADP 18
- INT 3
- FTH 6

I mostly run around with bastard sword, Grand Lance and Sea Bow.

Comment: Could you give more details on your character?

Comment: Firstly, you'll need to up your stats in order for this to work. This will only reduce a spell/miracle down to a base requirement of 10 Int/Fai. Secondly, there are way too many spells and way too many playstyles to pick just one. And finally, bringing down a spells requirement also affects its output. For example, casting "Great Soul Arrow" with an Int of 10 will do less damage overall, as your casting stat is lower than the base requirement (14).

Comment: I see this as a possible Good Subjective question. I don't think there's anything primarily opinion based about it, as a good answer would explain *why* a certain incense is best to use.

Comment: Maybe i should reformulate? which single spell/hex/miracle is worth using incense for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, anything that requires INT and FTH to do direct damage will require those stats to work properly.  Otherwise you might as well just pull out your bow and shoot them.

Early game, things like [Heal](https://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Heal), [Homeward](https://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Homeward), and [Replenishment](https://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Replenishment) are very useful.  However, at SL106, you have no problems replicating all of those effects with another item. At this late stage in the game, it is matter of convenience.

The most useful one may be Homeward for farming, but beyond that there really isn't anything low level that's genuinely useful.

If you already use Pyromancies, then you would have access to other things that makes the  low level Hex/Sorcery/Miracle based ones redundant, on top of being able to replicate it using an item.

[Warmth](https://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Warmth) is already one of the most powerful healing spell, so there's no point of using any Miracles at this late stage in game.  Flame weapon will already do what most of the other low level buffs will do, so that's pointless.

[Force](https://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Force) is maybe the only one that Pyromancy can't do, but it is a really niche effect and not generally useful.

Comment: Well, i have found that a bow generally works just fine (although i am still kind of choosing between dragonrider and sea one) for ranged combat against mobs.

Comment: It is just i kind of feel sad looking at all those spices that i have and don't use

Comment: If you are really into the game, at some point you'll hit 99 in all your main stats then you can go ham with the spices on some of the spells and do whatever you want... LIkewise a spell caster will look at all those weapons and armor and also be just as sad :)